# docker container not available at port 80 like it should

Tags: docker, port, containers

Im using docker registry and the docker frontend is listed as running when I invoke `docker ps` but it is not available at `localhost:80`:

```
e2a54694e434        konradkleine/docker-registry-frontend   "/bin/sh -c $START_S   26 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds        443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   serene_tesla
```

Comment: what is the value of `$START_S`?

Comment: That is the start script. More details can be found [here](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/konradkleine/docker-registry-frontend/dockerfile/).

Comment: What command did you use to start the container? Did you do `-p 80:80`?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use `boot2docker` or `docker-machine`? If so, you should use the VMs IP address instead of `localhost`.

- for `boot2docker` usually `192.168.59.103`.
- for `docker-machine`s IP address type `docker-machine ip <yourmachine>`.